# Powershell: Dynamically Convert Get-WMIObject to PSObject

Tags: c#, powershell, wmi, wmi-query, psobject

The majority of code examples I can find for working with Powershell and C# involve the use of PSobjects to return data from the Powershell scripts.  A large amount of examples on creating a PSObject involve taking data from Get-WMIObject and converting it to a PSObject.  This is done manually specifying each property to be carried over into the new PSObject from the results.  Is there anyway to dynamically convert the results from Get-WMIObject (whihc I believe is a ManagementObject) to a PSObject in Powershell?

Basically I'd want a function where regardless of what class of WMIObject I'd be using I'd be able to convert into a PSObject.  I've come across the .PSObject.Members call that can be used on the results of a Get-WMIObject call (just .PSObject doesn't seem to actually be anything valid).  So I am able to do the following:

```
$class = "Win32_ComputerSystem"
$psObject = New-Object PSObject
$properties = (Get-WMIObject -Class $class).PSObject.Members | where membertype -match "Property"

foreach($property in $properties)
{
    $psObject | Add-Member NoteProperty $property.name -Value $property.value
}
$psObject
```

But this gives me a much larger amount of results I would normally get from just calling Get-WMIObject.  Does anyone know a better way of converting or a way to further trim down these results to be closer to the standard output?  I would want it to remain generic where I could change the value of $class to any of the other WMIObject classes and it would still work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "standard properties" are stored in a property that is hidden on the original object, `PSStandardMembers`.

```
$obj = gwmi Win32_ComputerSystem
$psObject = $obj | select $obj.PSStandardMembers.DefaultDisplayPropertySet.ReferencedPropertyNames
```

Projects only the standard members into the custom PSObject.